# TypeError: unhashable type: 'Bunch' appears after selecting value from ipywidgets dropdown menu

Tags: python-3.x, ipywidgets

I'm getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'Bunch' after selecting value from ipywidgets dropdown menu. I know that the **testEvent** function itself works just fine.

```
testDict = {
'A': {'mean': 1354.95,'median': 1387.0},
'B': {'mean': 2252.52,'median': 1110.0},
'C': {'mean': 541.69,'median': 572.0},
'D': {'mean': 970.01,'median': 983.62}}
```

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
from branca.colormap import linear

dropdownMenu = widgets.Dropdown(options=['mean','median'],value='mean',description='Column:')
widgetOutput = widgets.Output()

def colEvent(col):   
    widgetOutput.clear_output()
    colorDic = {}
    namesList = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
    with widgetOutput:
        colormap = linear.YlGn_09.scale(
            min(nest[col] for nest in testDict.values()),
            max(nest[col] for nest in testDict.values()))
        for name in namesList:
            if testDict.get(name):        
                colorDic[name] = {}
                colorDic[name]=colormap(testDict.get(name).get(col))
            else:
                colorDic[name] = {}
                colorDic[name] = '#ffffffff'

dropdownMenu.observe(colEvent, names='value')
display(dropdownMenu)
display(widgetOutput)
```

The result after selecting for example median from the menu should look like this:

```
{'A': '#004529ff',
 'B': '#38a056ff',
 'C': '#ffffe5ff',
 'D': '#76c578ff',
 'E': '#ffffffff'}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know what is the problem now. I need to change "col" variable to col.new and then it works.

```
def colEvent(col):   
    widgetOutput.clear_output()
    colorDic = {}
    namesList = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
    with widgetOutput:
        colormap = linear.YlGn_09.scale(
                min(nest[col.new] for nest in testDict.values()),
                max(nest[col.new] for nest in testDict.values()))
        for name in namesList:
            if testDict.get(name):        
               colorDic[name] = {}
               colorDic[name]=colormap(testDict.get(name).get(col.new))
            else:
               colorDic[name] = {}
               colorDic[name] = '#ffffffff'
    display(colorDic)
```